# Why does SSMS highlight SUBSTRING in purple but RIGHT in grey?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I apologise for the trivial question, but I was trying to work out how to do a `RIGHT` in SQL so I experimentally typed `RIGHT` and it didn't highlight in purple, so I spent some time scratching my head about how to do this using substring and length, then I later discovered that `RIGHT` is perfectly valid.

How come it wasn't highlighted purple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because while you're *right* that `RIGHT()` is a function, `RIGHT` is also a keyword, as in `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. They have to pick one (SSMS is not smart enough to detect context). I face the same problem in the syntax highlighting plugin I use for my blogs - it either has to color all instances of `RIGHT` as grey, or all instances of `RIGHT` as purple.

(Also, if you have doubts about T-SQL syntax, don't waste your time trying to rely on IntelliSense to guide you - [consult the documentation, that's what it's for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx).)

Comment: If only they left the colour of UPDATE alone...